# NE555 stable frequency vs duty cycle change

Tags: pwm, 555

I am experimenting with NE555 trying to get it to output stable frequency as duty cycle is changed. Circuit is powered with a 9V DC supply. The schematic is attached. The R3 is here so that the charge and discharge currents are balanced. What happens is, the frequency is pretty much consistent in 50-90% duty cycle range (I get around 290Hz). However, if I lower duty cycle below 30% and further, the frequency gradually rises up to around 400 Hz. The frequency measurement is done with the UNI-T UT61E multimeter at LED cathode.

I was able to sort of improve it by attaching a 21k resistor from CONTROL pin to GND. In this case frequency at 50% duty cycle is around 320HZ, and around 360 Hz at both ends (10% and 90%). But that's not stable either. :) Is there any way to fix that?

I also noticed that NE555 becomes unstable if I rise power supply voltage above 12V. At duty cycle below 20% everything gets messed up and I get oscillations at around 5 KHz. Is it possible to fix that? The chip is supposed to run fine at 15v.

[image: astable rig]

Comment: Have a look at https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf?ts=1649399159353&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FNE555 figure 12 on page 11 note the connection of  RA, RB and C

Answer (score 2):

First thing is that you definitely should have power supply bypass capacitors close to the chip. You have stated you are using the NE555 (not one of the CMOS versions) which is particularly adept at drawing nasty current spikes. Perhaps 100nF very close to the chip, and in parallel with 10uF or 100uF. The spike is reportedly 100-200ns in duration and several hundred mA in magnitude. This may explain your 5kHz oscillation.

A change from 330Hz to 360Hz (345Hz +/-5% approximately) is not a particularly large change for a non-precise circuit like the 555. You should probably specify what you would consider 'stable'. Note that power supply fluctuations during the timing cycle will affect the timing since the 555 has no reference of any kind and depends on an internal resistor chain from the supply voltage to set thresholds. You've added C2 which has a time constant of about 20us with that divider.

Possibly reducing the 100nF timing cap to 10nF and increasing the pot and 1k resistors by 10:1 might improve things but then again it might not. It should reduce the voltage at the DISCH terminal in the 'on' state which could make things more symmetrical.

Answer (score 1):

The genius of the 555 design is that the internal references for the comparators are directly dependent on the supply voltage and nothing else.  This means that for the standard astable circuit, everything depends on the *ratios* of networks, not their absolute values.  Power supply influences are a small fraction of what they are in other R-C oscillator circuits, especially at higher operating voltages like 15 V.

But . . .

Yours is not the standard circuit.  In particular, it has two diodes in it.  Their forward voltage is independent of the power supply voltage, and now is a term in the charging/discharging current equations.  The currents deviate away from exponential as the wiper position approaches each end of the pot.  You can confirm this by changing to small signal Schottky diodes with a lower Vf.

The standard astable circuit has an inherent asymmetry.  The CMOS 555 datasheet has a symmetrical variant, driving the timing network with the output, leaving the discharge function unused.  This doesn't solve your problem, but it should improve output symmetry at the ends of the pot.  You might be able to eliminate R3.  While this circuit works with both the bipolar and CMOS 555 . . .

Another avenue of improvement is to change to CMOS 555.  The output stage isn't nearly as beefy, but it is way more symmetrical in both output impedance and headroom.

Don't worry about the 555's age.  30 years after its introduction, it still was selling in the *billions* of units per year.

Comment: This was actually the first thing I tried, driving the capacitor with pin 3. It yields the same result. I am not concerned about symmetry, I am looking for frequency stability. I don't understand why it changes at the low end.

Comment: 1. Did things improve with the diode change?  2.  To be clear, pin 3 drives the resistors.  3.  Also, stability or linearity?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to use a second 555.

Use the first one to generate pulses at a stable frequency, then use that to trigger the second that would be setup as a one-shot with a variable pulse width. As the pulse width is increased towards 1/f the duty cycle would approach 100%.

[image: variable duty cycle constant frequency]

Duty cycle with R1 = 1 ohm
[image: duty cycle with R=1 ohm]

Duty cycle with R1 = 47k
[image: duty cycle with R=47k]